# What's the difference between DBD::Pg and DBD::PgPP

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbd

What's the difference between the two PostgreSQL `perl` client implementations DBD::Pg and DBD::PgPP?

Comment: Why didn't you read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::PgPP)?

Comment: I wanted to answer the question myself... I guess I have to hit the checkbox when creating the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to CPAN, DBD::PgPP is a pure Perl implementation of the PostgreSQL driver. DBD:pg has some low-level c implementation.
If you need only Perl as a dependency, DBD::PgPP is worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Use DBD::Pg if it's available, it will be faster than DBD::PgPP because some parts are implemented in C, whereas DBD::PgPP is pure perl (which is what PP stands for).

Answer (score 0):

Summing up http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=457530:

*DBD::PgPP* pros:

- easier to install than `DBD::Pg` because it doesn't depend on the external dependency
- more up-to-date (see below)
- pure `perl` implementation

*DBD::Pg* pros:

- actively maintained by the PostgreSQL team
- has a more friendly PostgreSQL interface
- offers support for `COPY` (see http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-3.5.3/Pg.pm#COPY_support for details)